# p5.js: How can I make text appear when my mouse hovers over a different element in the sketch in processing?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I have text in my sketch file that appears constantly on the screen. When I hover on that piece of text, I want to display more information on that introductory text on the corner of the browser window, without affecting the rest of the screen. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Have you think about using a `position: absolute` for your second element ?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to know what you want exactly without seeing the code, but here's some pointers:

You could create an element using `createElement` and add an on hover event. When you hover over that element you can display your help text. In the example below I've created an element `hoverOverMe` which sets a boolean value `showInfo` to true if it's being hovered over and false if it isn't - then I'm displaying some text based on that.

```js
let hoverOverMe;
let showInfo = false;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  hoverOverMe = createElement("h1", "Hover over me");
  hoverOverMe.mouseOver(() => showInfo = true);
  hoverOverMe.mouseOut(() => showInfo = false);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  
  if (showInfo) {
    textSize(40);
    text("I'm info text", width / 2, height/2);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@0.10.2/lib/p5.js"></script>
```